# will or present progressive in this case

Tags: future-tense

Buy some pizzas for your lunch! We **are not**  **coming back** or **won't come back** home because our friends has just invited us

i think second one is better because it has not been planned, it is a decision taken at the time of speaking  but is  the firsty one  also idiomatic

Comment: The first seems much more idiomatic to me. I think you're misinterpreting "planned" - it doesn't have to have been planned in advance: we're expressing a plan, even if that plan has only just been formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both work, and the first is more idiomatic. In informal speech, when someone is saying what they confidently intend to do, they'll usually use the present progressive instead of "will". If they're uncertain (e.g. because it's farther away in time) then they'll use "will".

(The actual distinction here isn't present vs. future, it's realis vs. irrealis. If they're confident enough in their plan, they'll speak of it as a fact.)