# the difference between be going to and will

Tags: grammar

I heard this from an English teacher .Is that correct?

- Watch out! The baby is going to fall.
- Watch out! The dog will bite you.

> He said that we usually use the form be going to with expressions like look out! or watch out! , but in the second example when we use you or your we use will + inf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [will or present progressive in this case](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208926/will-or-present-progressive-in-this-case)